# How to get best performance of NodeJS application

Tags: node.js, performance, optimization

If we use ForEach, Promise all and optimize DB query properly in the entire NodeJS application then is it sufficient that Node application will utilise machine resources like processors, cores and threads properly and give the best performance?

I have tried with worker node implementation but I am not sure whether work node is required if we make sure proper use of ForEach, Promise all and optimize DB query is sufficient to achieve best performance.

Comment: Make sure you cluster your application for multiple cores, or else it runs a single event loop on a single core.

Comment: You get the absolute best performance of a NodeJS app by not having it do any work. This question is too broad to answer in any meaningful way.

Answer (score 0):

NodeJs is single-threaded. It is optimized itself by event-loop.

You can run **cluster** (built-in module in nodejs) for utilizing of multi-core systems. It creates few child processes for requests.

I dont think that **forEach** can improve performance. Why would?
You can improve performance with **Promise-all** to execute requests parallel and not wait for each request to be finished sequentially.

The problem usually lies with a non-optimized database, missing indexes, incorrect indexing, poorly normalized database, incorrectly chosen database for the given data, poorly constructed queries (the database optimizer fails to select an index for execution), etc.